# DataReader or DataTable to bind Repeater?

Tags: c#, datatable, datareader

Till now, I am using `DataTable` to bind `Repeater`. But for new Project, I want to improve its performance so I want to know that which one is better to bind `Repeater`, `DataReader` or `DataTable` ?

I will fetch around 20 rows at a time as I am using `Custom Paging` with Repeater. Should I fill data in List or use `DataReader` or `DataTabl`e directly as `DataSource` ?

Please help me choose any one for better performance. or any other better option ?

Comment: You are micro optimizing things. If you have performance issues then there is most likely something else to optimize. For example the query, why does it take a long time to query 20 rows? A `DataTable` is filled from a `DataAdapter` which also uses a `DataReader` so there's almost no difference.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, No, query is working fine. I just want to know if one of them have any performance issue.

Comment: Then i guess that my coment answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are micro optimizing things. If you have performance issues then there is most likely something else to optimize. For example the query, why does it take a long time to query 20 rows? A `DataTable` is filled from a `DataAdapter` which also uses a `DataReader` so there's almost no difference.

Choose whatever you find most readable.

Comment: `DataReader` is connected architecture while `DataTable` is disconnected so is it better practice to open and close connection while retrieving data ? I wont fetch more than 50 rows at a time.

Comment: @JeetenParmar: but you have asked what is better as DataSource for your repeater, a `DataTable` or using a `DataReader`. There's no difference since even a `DataReader` is disconnected once you've assigned it as datasource and `dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)` also uses a `DataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

directly bind to control will better than fill in list then bind to control.